# UINavigationBar contentMode not being set

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make the background of the `UINavigationBar` an image, and the image isn't the exact size of the bar. I can't seem to set the `contentMode` of the bar correctly for some reason. This is the code I have:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // ...


    let image = UIImage(named: object?.imageName ?? "")
    navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 0
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    UIView.animate(withDuration: Double(UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration), animations: {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 1
    })
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, or maybe `contentMode` just doesn't do anything for `UINavigationBar`.

What's currently happening is the background image is just presented again like mosaic

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create UIView and add Image and Text to it, but you must set constraints

```
    let titleView = UIView()
    titleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40)

    let containerView = UIView()
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    titleView.addSubview(containerView)

    let profileImageView = UIImageView()
    profileImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    containerView.addSubview(profileImageView)

    profileImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView

    titleView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: 
    self, action: #selector(func)))
```

I hope that I helped you

Comment: Didn't completely work. Ended up adding the image to the `VC`'s `view` and put it behind the `UINavigationController`